# UITextView Slants in the DesignView and at RunTime

Tags: iphone, uilabel, swift4, xcode9.4, ios11.4

[image]:
[image]

**Situation:**

As shown in the Image above, I have designed the layout using **Xcode 9** and soon after the design was complete, I noticed a weird `layout` issue.

If you look closely, you can observe the `UILabels` are being "slant" or "tilted" towards the right.

**Question:**

Any idea why is this happening? I observed this first time after developing half of the application. It has never happened before.

**Note:** There is no `Swift` code written for designing, everything is aligned using `AutoLayout`, `StackView` and `UILabel`. If you want me to provide any code, I will post it on request.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: might just be a rendering issue in the simulator. Did you try it on device?

Comment: It's appearing in the simulator as well as in the design view on Xcode. It has never happened like this before. I did not check on the device though. @iOSer

Comment: not quite sure why its happening but Im pretty sure it wont show up on device

Comment: Okay I'll test it in iPhone5s now and hope it works right there. @iOSer Thanks anyway.

Comment: @iOSer unfortunately, Same thing happens on the device, iPhone5s. I think there is some problem in the StackView I used. What do you think?

Comment: @UmangBurman use stackview programmatically with your collectionview if your layout is two column and load xib (xib will contain textfield and label) in your stackview.

Comment: Okay Mahesh, so you mean that it's all because of stackview not used programmatically?

Comment: @MaheshDangar StackViews do not execute properly in MainStoryboard view?

Comment: Can you please provide the view layout hierarchy. Also, do you apply any transforms to any views in the code?

Comment: @Vlad I did not apply any transforms, as a matter of fact I do not know how to do that. It's just plain old label. It looks straight but inner content looks slant.

Comment: @UmangBurman Can you open that VC while debugging and go into "View UI Hierarchy" under the debug navigator (command + 7 on the keyboard). Then take a screenshot and post it here. It will show us which view is slanted.

There are instructions here if you're not sure what I mean: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-SW2

Comment: @Vlad I've updated the question, is this what you were asking for? Do tell me if you need anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used an image editor to add some perfectly horizontal red lines to your storyboard screen shot. The red lines make it easier to see why it looks “slanted”:

[image: storyboard with red lines]

All of your labels have perfectly horizontal baselines, and all of your grey labels are correctly aligned (vertically) with each other.

**The “slant” appears because your black “---” labels are not aligned vertically with each other.**

You didn't post enough information for me to explain why your dash labels aren't aligned vertically, but perhaps you now have enough information to track down the problem yourself. If not, edit your question to include more information about how the dash labels are configured and constrained.

#### UPDATE

I have uploaded a storyboard [to this gist](https://gist.github.com/mayoff/9f07c14b21b497b5e229fc6f4af7cb02) that shows how I would lay out this view.

Here's what I did in my storyboard:

Everywhere that you have a row of two labels side by side, put them in a horizontal stack view with alignment set to “First Baseline” and distribution set to “Fill Equally”. If you need padding around the row, change the stack view's Layout Margins (in the Size inspector) to “Fixed” and set the margins to get the padding you want. Thus:

[image: storyboard screen shot]

Here's my document outline:

[image: document outline]

All labels are configured with horizontal content hugging priority 251, vertical content hugging priority 1000, and both axes' content compression resistance priorities set to 1000:

[image: label intrinsic content size priorities]

All of the horizontal row stack views are configured with “Fixed” layout margins with left and right set to 8, and top and bottom set according to what is needed. For example, the stack view containing the “Available Credits” and “Used Credits” labels has these margins:

[image: credits labels row margins]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Perhaps I noticed this myself before posting the question. It'll be great if you can suggest me what information do you require. According to the AutoLayout Everything is aligned with equal widths and height.

Comment: Thank you for all the efforts that you have put in to answer the question. I'm sorry I could not award you bounty because my account was suspended, Only today it got back on.